# How to set url mapping in Spring MVC for not existing resources?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, url-mapping

What I want to do is that when user enters url which leads nowhere, I mean there is no resources by this url than special mapping should work.

For example, I have next controller:

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return new ModelAndView("mainPage");
    }
}
```

This mapping works when when user enters {contextPath}/ or {contextPath}/login
Now i want to map all other urls, I do like this:

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcome() {
        return new ModelAndView("mainPage");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView notFound() {
        return new ModelAndView("customized404Page");
    }
}
```

Now when user enters invalid path for example {contextPath}/sdfsdf customized404Page is shown to him

But last mapping is more general and and it works always and that is why first mapping doesn`t work.

Question:
How to map all invalid urls?
Or maybe there is some simplier way to to this in Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to have a customized 404 Page is to configure them in the `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

---

When a simple `jsp` is not enough, because you need a full fledged Spring controller, then you can map the location to the controller`s mapping:

```
@Controller
public class HttpErrorController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/error404")
    public String error404() {
        ...
        return "error404.jsp";
    }
}

<error-page>
  <error-code>404</error-code>
  <location>/error404</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use session filter to achieve this.

Check this link.
http://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial